# No puedo mostrar consulta con la funcion SUM de SQL en VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente  al momento de querer  traer los registros calculados de una base de datos

```
Sub TotalSuperficie()
Call conexion

'La variable  recordst, fue definida de tipo GLOBAL  en la funcion  conexion de la siguiente manera:
'Global recordst As ADODB.Recordset
', esto lo tengo en un modulo dentro del desarrollo

Set recordst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Sum(Extensión) As TotSuperf " _
        & "FROM infopaises")
Range("I14").Value = recordst!TotSuperf   
End Sub
```

al ejecutar la consulta me muestra el siguiente error:

"Se requiere un objeto"

Comment: Hay alguna hoja activa? CurrentDB está bien inicializado?

Comment: Hola, no das mucho detalle pero prueba del siguiente modo:
Range("I14").Value = recordst.Fields!TotSuperf

Answer (score 1):

No contestaste el comentario, pero lo coloco como respuesta por si otros tienen el mismo dilema. El error de objeto que te sale es porque aparentemente no está reconociendo tu línea (aunque no la indicas):

```
Range("I14").Value = recordst!TotSuperf
```

Entonces debes colocar así:

```
Range("I14").Value = recordst.Fields!TotSuperf
```

Saludos

Comment: de acuerdo esa era la solución. saludos y un abrazo!.